# Converting a resource set into dictionary using linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
var rm = new ResourceManager(sometype);

var resourceSet = rm.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
```

I want to convert the above resource set into dictionary. Currently I'm doing through manually by looping as below.

```
var resourceDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (var r in resourceSet)
{
  var dicEntry = (DictionaryEntry)r;
  resourceDictionary.Add(dicEntry.Key.ToString(), dicEntry.Value.ToString());          
}
```

How I can do achieve that easily using linq?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Try this:

```
var resourceDictionary = resourceSet.Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
                                    .ToDictionary(r => r.Key.ToString(),
                                                  r => r.Value.ToString());
```

Comment: completely forgot of this `Cast<>()` method!

Answer (score 3):

```
var resourceDictionary = resourceSet.Select(r => (DictionaryEntry) r)
                                     .ToDictionary(dicEntry => dicEntry.Key.ToString(),
                                                dicEntry => dicEntry.Value.ToString());
```